# Having trouble with javascript alerts

Tags: javascript, alerts

this is for class so the actual content of the page doesnt actually matter. for some reason, my alerts just aren't showing up. ill paste my code.

```js
//Evin Round
//01-19-2022
//Story Time

alert("Today, we will be making a story together. I will need information from you to help.");

let aName = prompt("Give me a name.");

let color = prompt("How about a color?");

let number = prompt("And a number?");

    let movie = prompt("What is one of your favorite movies?");

    let animal = prompt("Please name an animal.");

    let adj = prompt("Finally, name an adjective.");

    alert("Now, check the console for your story!");

    console.log("There once was a gentlman named " + aName + " who had " + color + " eyes and " + number + " toes.");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: gold;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!--Evin Round-->
<!--01-09-23-->
<!--CE02 Story Time-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
  <title>Story Time</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Matt Daemon</h1>
    <h2>Is a Cereal Killer.</h2>
    <p>Comedy gold.</p>
  </div>

  <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried messing with the linkage of javascript to html but the console shows that it IS connected so i must have messed up code somewhere. I just dont know where.

Comment: Your code is okay.  A browser may get fussy about displaying a lot of alerts and may give you an option to mute them.  What's the browser / platform?

Comment: I'm on chrome. It could possibly be that I'm on data! I appreciate the help. I was getting very frustrated.

Comment: Have you checked that your js is actually loaded? Use the Network tab in browser tools to ensure the js file is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your alert is working fine for me!Sounds like you have checked to prevent the additional dialogue box popup.Change browser or reset the browser and try again